# SPRING MVC post method call not working

Tags: spring-mvc

By JSP has below :

```
<h2>Student Information</h2>
<form:form method="POST" action="/HelloWeb/addStudent">
   <table>
```

and my java controller code has below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb") Student student,
            ModelMap model) {
```

when i try to hit the post doesnt work i,e /HelloWeb/addStudent,
I tried making both places /HelloWeb/addStudent or just /addStudent that doesnt work.

FYI : HelloWeb here is the DispatchServletName given in web,xml

I am trying example given in site 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm

I apologize if i am asking very basic easisest issue, BUt tried this @ late nite and fed up so requesting ppl to help/suggest

Comment: remove the / before addStudent in the RequestMapping.

Comment: The action shouldn't have the /HelloWeb prefix. Is there a Post being sent at all? To which URL? Have you declared the usage of the spring form taglinb in the JSP?

Answer (score 0):

The  attribute in jsp require modelAddribute or commandName which  is the class instance of the domain object. You did not specify it. So the

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="SpringWeb" action="/HelloWeb/addStudent">.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard way to do form post submission in spring. You need to do GET request mapping to map/bind the Student table with jsp, and POST mapping to submit jsp form data. An example in your case would be.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb") Student student) {
    return "addstudentJsp";   // your jsp page name where the spring:form is placed
```

In jsp page do this

```
<h2>Student Information</h2>
<form:form modelAttribute="SpringWeb">
  <form:input id="name" path="name" type="text" class="form-control" />
  <form:errors path="name" cssClass="text-danger"></form:errors>
  // your student fields
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form:form>
```

Now again in your controller have a post request method like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb") Student student, @BindingResult result) {
    //Call to your data persistence layer like StudentService
}
```

The modelAttribute does the binding for you

Comment: Also if you are  new and learning spring mvc I would recommend to stop xml based configuration and try to learn Java based configuration(Annotation based)

Comment: Ok this is an old question didn not noticed before

Answer (score -1):

I faced same problem, I just rename my project "HelloWeb" and the problem was solved.